# Cypress - intercept parameter of the api response body and set it as a variable/alias

Tags: typescript, cypress

I've found some documentation about storing hardcoded environment variables - [https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables](https://Cypress%20environment%20variables), but I would like to do something similar, yet not with a variable I've hardcoded before but with a variable that will be set based on response from intercepted api request duing my tests (I want to save one parameter from the response and reuse later). Please, just, bear in mind I'm new to Cypress, javascript, typescript (which I'm obliged to use instead of classic js) and even coding in general, so I might be missing basic concepts

So, after hours of struggling I've managed to intercept a value from one parameter (applicationId) in order to use it later in cypress request event  (cy.request function) but only with .then function

```
cy.intercept("POST", "**/application").as("startApplication");
  cy.get("@startApplication")
    .its("response")
    .then((response) => {
      const applicationId = response.body.applicationId;
      cy.request({
        method: "POST",
        url: `${apiBaseUrl}/e2e/application/${applicationId}`,
      });
    });
```

What I need to do is to reuse this applicationId few more times during my e2e tests in order to call other api endpoints later... I don't want to redo the same thing each time, meaning cy.get + .then (cy.request). I would like to do cy.request right off the bat with this applicationId I already managed to get, without doing cy.get("@startApplication") again.

Btw, for what I care it doesn't have to be an environmental variable, it might be alias, const or whatever that would let me nicely reuse that applciationId later...

Answer (score 0):

If all of the tests are in the same spec file, you can define the variable outside of the `cy.get()` to set the value.

```js
describe('some tests', () => {
  let applicationId;
  
  it('tests something', () => {
    cy.get("@startApplication")
    .its("response")
    .then((response) => {
      applicationId = response.body.applicationId;
      cy.request({
        method: "POST",
        url: `${apiBaseUrl}/e2e/application/${applicationId}`,
      });
    });
  });

  it('logs applicationId', () => {
    cy.log(applicationId);
  });
})
```

Depending on the setup you have, it may make sense to do some conditional logic to check if the variable has been set in a `beforeEach`

```js
describe('some tests', () => {
  let applicationId;
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.intercept("POST", "**/application").as("startApplication");
    cy.visit('/foo'); // assuming a visit to the webpage triggers this
    if (!applicationId) { // only run this if applicationId is falsy.
      cy.get("@startApplication")
        .its("response")
        .then((response) => {
          applicationId = response.body.applicationId;
          cy.request({
            method: "POST",
            url: `${apiBaseUrl}/e2e/application/${applicationId}`,
          });
        });
      }
  });
});
```